# Different Desktop for Different Users

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager, desktop-environment, gdm

How do I (if possible) set different default desktop environments for different users in linux?

e.g. when user X login, Gnome Shell starts, when user Y login, Gnome starts. (I'm using ubuntu if it matters).

Comment: By Gnome, are you referring to GNOME 2?

Comment: No, Gnome 3. is it the same as gnome shell?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11068/688

Comment: @Tshepang - Thanks for the link, but in general (if I take two different desktops) is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking to do that for a large number of users (so you want an automated way), or do you want to know how each user can make a choice that sticks between sessions? (The latter works out of the box on Ubuntu 10.04 and most other systems, does your environment lack a choice on the gdm login screen?)

Comment: @Gilles - I want each user to choose for himself, I don't need an automated way. Regarding your last question - I need to check it again.

Comment: I use a window manager called `weston`, it's pretty simple. I log into a text terminal, then type "weston-launch". The thing with weston is I can do that in one or more of the TTYs and then I can switch between different weston sessions using Ctrl-Al-F[1-8].
I only know 2 options that support running in this way: `weston` and `sway`. Both still immature but usable.
Anyway with these you can just add `weston-launch` or `sway` at the bottom of the user's `.bashrc` and the WM will fire up as soon as they log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GNOME 3:

- You will need to log in with each user and specify this in **Applications** -> **System Tools** -> **System Settings** -> **System Info** -> **Graphics** --> **Forced Fallback Mode**. **Fallback Mode** is old GNOME interface and the other Mode is GNOME Shell (standard) mode.

For other desktops:

- You do the selection using your login manager. It should have an option to select which session you want to log in, and if you change from default, it should ask if you want to permanently use the new session. Session in this case refers to any Desktop (GNOME, KDE, XFCE, ...).

Comment: What if I want user x to get Gnome3 and user y to get awesome or some other window manager? Can this not be set at the gdm login screen like in gnome2 days?

Comment: Good question, and me not know the answer.